# Using throws keyword and handling it in the main rather than handling it in the method in which it occurs

Tags: java, exception

If I add the throws keyword in the method signature and handle it in my main() inside my TestClass{}, is it a good approach or should I handle the exception in the method in which it occurs fooBar(), which approach is recommended or what are the trade-offs between the two. Sorry this question might seem a little weird, just a newbie in Java.

```java
public class Foo {

    //private fields

    public Foo() {
        //ctor
    }

    //accessors and mutators

    //method that throws exception
    public void fooBar() throws FooBarException {
        throw new FooBarException();
    }

}
```

Comment: It really depends on the code.... Lets say you're creating an invoice pdf, and you're loading a logo image onto the pdf, and the image fails to load.... that would be a scenario where you would want to handle it in the code with a try catch... because you wouldn't want the whole pdf to not be created for such a small error... now lets say you're creating an invoice pdf and all the invoice data fails to load, that would be an appropriate situation to have the calling method handle the error

Comment: There is no universal answer (which is why both approaches are allowed); whichever location is best suited to handle (pun intended) the error should handle it.

Comment: It depends - if you can reasonably handle that exception within the method, do it within your method. If you don't know how you should respond in the context of the method, throw the exception. *Never* suppress exceptions.

Comment: if I had an Account class with a withdrawal method in that case would I handle the exception inside the method or would I use the throws keyword. It's a bit confusing to know when to use it tho as a beginner.

Comment: Think of it this way.... you're calling a method `withdrawalMoney()` and it fails to withdrawal money.... is that something the caller of that method should have to handle? Or is that something the caller wouldn't necessarily care about?

Comment: @Avi Can you be more explicit about what you mean by "Never suppress exceptions"?

Comment: @RobOhRob I disagree with your example.  If the PDF isn’t what it’s supposed to be, the method should fail.  If the logo image is invalid or missing, someone screwed up, and needs to be notified that they screwed up.

Comment: @RobOhRob I would prefer to handle it in the `withdrawalMoney()` since I would most probably already have an `Account` class. I still not 100% sure tho.

Comment: @tim so lets say you call `withdrawalMoney(500)`... and after you call `sendMoneyToFriend(500)`...if you handled the exception in withdrawalMoney() then `sendMoneyToFriend(500)` would still happen afterwards

Comment: @VGR disagree.... it's an invoice pdf...a logo is nice, but it's not worth stopping invoices from being sent in production #priorities

Comment: @RobOhRob so i should handle it in their respective methods?

Comment: @tim there is no single answer to that question... but if you call `withdrawalMoney(500)` and it fails to withdrawal money, would you as the caller, want to know that happened? Or would you want to proceed with all other method calls/operations?

Comment: @RobOhRob But if I write something like 
`public void fooBar() {
  try {
   throw new FooBarException();
  }
  catch(FooBarException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }`
I would still know where the error occurred and proceed with the operations.

Comment: @tim By "*Never* suppress exceptions", I mean that you should never ignore them completely (for example, with an empty catch block). All exceptions should either be appropriately handled, or thrown to a caller that can appropriately handle the exception. If an exception is not appropriately handled, then it is perfectly logical for your application to terminate.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the scope of `try block` should be as small as possible.

```
public void fooBar(){
        try{
         //Lines that can through error
        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            //Handle exception Here
            //e.printStackTrace();

        /*
         other code that will not throw any error
        */
    }
```

or if the whole block may throw the error then

```
    public void fooBar() throws FooBarException {

    }
    //Handle in the exception where you calling the method
```